# Google colab : Access Denied You don't have permission to access "website" on this server

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I am trying to scrape website on google colab using beautiful soup. I am able to scrape the content on my local machine but when I am trying to scrape it on cloud. I am getting an error.

> '\nAccess Denied\n\nAccess Denied\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Spardha-Mithra-IAS-KAS-Coaching-Centre-Opposite-Maruthi-Medicals-Vijayanagar/080PXX80-XX80-140120184741-R6P8_BZDET?" on this server.\nReference #18.740f1160.1544263996.61a6bb6e\n\n\n'

When I run the same code on my local machine it works fine tho.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Spardha-Mithra-IAS-KAS-Coaching-Centre-Opposite-Maruthi-Medicals-Vijayanagar/080PXX80-XX80-140120184741-R6P8_BZDET?xid=QmFuZ2Fsb3JlIEJhbmsgRXhhbSBUdXRvcmlhbHM='
res  = requests.get(url, headers  = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
print(res)
```

Output :

```
<Response [403]>
```

Why is this happening and is there any way to get rid of it.

Comment: it fine in my colab account, are you doing multiple request (loop)?

Comment: No I am trying to run it only once. Has the host closed the connection for me. Is my colab blocked from the website. Because its running on my local PC. So IP address cannot be the reason. Right??

Comment: What do you think since this is not a general problem and has occured only to me should I delete this question??

Comment: you don't need to delete this. try change your IP address

Comment: @ewwink I tried changing IP address it did not work. But when I tried it with my other google account in chrome incognito window mode. It worked. Can you tell me why is it happening.?

Comment: on cloud the URL using `http` or `https` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is server-side rate-limiting. Your code works fine for me in colab.
You might try colab's "Reset all runtimes" feature to get assigned a new VM, to rule out any side-effects from other notebook code you've run.